# Descending order object based on keys

Tags: javascript, json

I am using some API and they return json in following format , problem is they send keys as floating number.I cannot modify their backend part to make proper json.So I am looking for quickfix to show following data in descending order.

```
220: {CE: {…}, PE: {…}}
225: {CE: {…}, PE: {…}}
230: {CE: {…}, PE: {…}}
235.23: {CE: {…}, PE: {…}}
240.32: {CE: {…}, PE: {…}}
245: {CE: {…}, PE: {…}}
250: {CE: {…}, PE: {…}}
255.12: {CE: {…}, PE: {…}}
```

I want to reverse it in descending order , I was trying to figure out how to do it for past 3 hours.

I tried following code

```
function reverseObject(object) {
        var newObject = {};
        var keys = [];
        for (var key in object) {
            keys.push(key);
        }
        for (var i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

          var value = object[keys[i]];
          newObject[keys[i]]= value;
        }       

        return newObject;
      }
```

Comment: Do you even care about keeping the keys? Objects don't have guaranteed iteration order, so it seems more like you want to generate an array of the objects in descending order of the original keys, is that correct?

Comment: keys is important for me , its the price , I want to display price in descending order in my html.

Comment: you get not descending ordered keys of an object, if the key is an 32 bit integer. these items are sorted by this keys ascending.

Comment: Then don't generate an object, because your generated object won't be any closer to your goal of having a guaranteed iteration order.

Comment: Convert it to something that isn't an object, then sort it using methods available to things of the type you choose.

Answer (score 1):

This will create an array of tuples `[['255.12', {CE: {…}, PE: {…}}],['250', {CE: {…}, PE: {…}}], …]` using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
function entriesDescending (object) {
  return Object
    .entries(object)
    .sort(([a], [b]) => b - a)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const response = {
  220: {CE: 'foo', PE: 'bar'},
  225: {CE: 'foo', PE: 'bar'},
  230: {CE: 'foo', PE: 'bar'},
  235.23: {CE: 'foo', PE: 'bar'},
  240.32: {CE: 'foo', PE: 'bar'},
  245: {CE: 'foo', PE: 'bar'},
  250: {CE: 'foo', PE: 'bar'},
  255.12: {CE: 'foo', PE: 'foo'},
}

const fromEntries = (acc, [key, value]) => ({...acc, [key]: value})

const byNumberKey = ([a], [b]) => a - b

const sortKeys = obj =>
  Object.entries(obj)
    .sort(byNumberKey)
    .reduce(fromEntries, {})
  
console.log(
  sortKeys(response)
)
```

Comment: 1. This is ascending order. 2. As was pointed out multiple times in comments, iteration order of objects is not guaranteed by the specification, so you're better off leaving it an array form (the intermediate result before calling `.reduce()`). 3. Your `fromEntries()` method makes a copy of the accumulator on every iteration of `reduce()`, so even if that was a good idea, it's really inefficient.